# OkHttp for Android: why onFailure sometimes still works when setText on TextView without using Handler

Tags: android, okhttp

I have just started learning OkHttp. My sample code as below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "OkHttp";
    private TextView mTextView;
    private Handler mHandler;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody requestBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                .add("grant_type", "password")
                .add("username", "bnk")
                .add("password", "bnk")
                .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://...")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                mTextView.setText(e.toString());
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                    final String message = jsonObject.toString(5);
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, message);
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mTextView.setText(message);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I know that I should use `Handler` to `setText` for `TextView` inside `onResponse`, however, with `onFailure`, I don't use `Handler` and check the result when `onFailure` called. It's strange that sometimes my app crashes with `android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`, sometime it works (I mean the `TextView` can display the `Exception`).

I am new to OkHttp.

### Update

From @NightlyNexus comments below, I try checking `Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()` and the result is always `FALSE`, however, as I said, the app still sometimes works. Please refer to the following screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Someone who has just down vote, can you give the reason why you do so? If I have a mistake, I will correct it

Comment: Neither the onResponse nor the onFailure methods are going to be called on the thread that called `newCall(...)`.  You should post back to your UI/main thread with your `Handler` in both cases.

Comment: @NightlyNexus I know that, however, I don't understand why sometime the app works normally (mean that the TextView can display exception message without using Handler). Thanks!

Comment: Interesting.  If you can reproduce this, can you confirm that `Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()`?

Comment: @NightlyNexus Do you mean that I will put this line inside onFailure?

Comment: Yes, put that line in onFailure().  Log the output of that or set a breakpoint.  Find out if that is true when it does not crash and successfully sets the text to the exception's toString().

Comment: @NightyNexus ok, I will do that soon and tell you the result. Thanks for your comments :-)

Comment: Interesting.  So, sometimes, `setText` will work off the main/UI thread?  Seems like that should never work in Android.

Comment: @NightlyNexus: that's why I find it strange issue. However, it only happens in real phone device, not in emulator although the same API. I have not tested many other APIs yet